# How to clear cache in SUDS before initialization?

Tags: python, suds

The `SUDS` module has built in method for cache clear like `client.options.cache.clear()`. The main problem is that i need to create `client` first and only then clear the cache... Is there some method to clear it before the initialization ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following option from the [docs](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation):

```
client.set_options(cache=None)
```

It is not exactly what you asked but may be useful.